# Making a private inherited inner template public via a using directive

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

I'm trying to use a `using` directive to bring in the `public` access declaration of a derived class some inner class template declared in the base. Code:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:    
    template<typename U>
    struct Inner;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived: private Base<T>
{
public:
    using typename Base<T>::template Inner; // make it visible
    Inner<T>* ptr; // no need for typename here, non-qualified name
};

int main() {}
```

Neither g++ nor clang++ compile this code, both complaining about

> error: expected unqualified-id before 'template'

As far as I know, `Inner` is a dependent template name, so one should use `::template` when qualifying its name, and also a `typename` before, since `Base<T>::Inner` is a dependent type. I've tried all possible combinations with/without `typename/template`, and none compile. Is there any way of using `Inner` in the `public` section of `Derived`?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#109

Comment: @T.C. "can be written with `->template`"?

Comment: @Barry Note that the original example in that issue was for a member function template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not possible. A *using-declaration* is, from [namespace.udecl]:

> `using` `typename`<sub>opt</sub> *nested-name-specifier* *unqualified-id* ;

But an *unqualified-id* can't be a class template.

You could just make an alias instead:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived: private Base<T>
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    using Inner = typename Base<T>::template Inner<U>;

    Inner<T>* ptr;
};
```

Comment: Why cannot an *unqualified-id* be a class template? AFAIK, `Inner<U>` is an unqualified-id, and it is a class template.

Comment: @vsoftco Just by the grammar, there's no allowance for the `template` keyword anywhere. `using Base<T>::template Inner<T>` is explicitly disallowed as it's a *template-id*. You can do `using Base<T>::Inner;`, but that doesn't actually help you at all so I'm not even entirely sure what it does.